# jQuery scrolling div with user until bottom of containing div is reached

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to find a jquery solution for scrolling a div on my product pages within the boundaries of it's containing div.

The main content on my product pages is split into two columns. The left column contains the product images, while the right column contains the product options. The issue is that the right column options content is extremely longer than the left column. By the time the user has viewed all the product options, the left column content has completely left the screen, and the user can not even see the images for the options they selected.

I've created a jsfiddle so you can easily understand what I just said :)
http://jsfiddle.net/gd7o6y91/

As you can see on the jsfiddle, I need the `.left-column` div to scroll with the user until it has reached the bottom of the `.container` div. Anyone have any ideas on how I can accomplish this with jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code might help you.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var marginTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var limit = $(".container").height() - $(".left-column").height();
    if(marginTop < limit )
        $(".left-column").css("margin-top",marginTop);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gd7o6y91/3/

Comment: Excellent. This is perfect except for one thing. While scrolling, the moving div locks to the bottom of the screen. Is it possible for it to lock in the middle? Here's your solution on my live site: http://customshop.yandasmusic.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=25&product_id=50

Comment: you can modify limit value for adjusting div at center.

$(window).scroll(function(){
var marginTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var limit = $(".container").height() - $(".left-column").height();
    if(marginTop < limit )
        $(".left-column").css("margin-top",marginTop);
});

Comment: So from looking at it, the code detects how far the user has scrolled down on the page, and just adds that value to the top margin of the moving div, so I somehow need to get it to ignore the first 400 pixels of scrolling or so?

Comment: yes. for now you can do this by subtracting 400 from limit variable. I am looking for some good solution. i will update answer accordingly

Comment: Hey @Sachin Kadam, Im having trouble adding a value to the variable in order to offset the margin top. is this syntax correct?                 $(window).scroll(function(){
                var addHeight = 400;
                var marginTop = $(window).scrollTop() + addHeight;
                var limit = $(".product-content-columns").height() - $(".product_page-left").height();
                if(marginTop < limit )
                $(".product_page-left").css("margin-top",marginTop);
                });

Comment: I think, you need to subtract height.I update jsfiddle. please check http://jsfiddle.net/gd7o6y91/12/

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sachin Kadam. From what I can tell, subtracting the offset height from the variable "limit" just changes the stopping point at which the div will stop moving when it reaches the bottom of ".container". I think what I really need to do is subtract the offsetHeight value from the actual css value generated by $(".product_page-left").css("margin-top",marginTop); . What would be the syntax to do that?

Comment: Just a quick update, while the code you provided in your fiddle is correct for the html in the fiddle, I needed a bit more for it to work on my live site, as there were other html elements to take into account. I made a few edits to your code snippit on my live site. Would you mind checking to make sure I'm not making some huge syntax mistake?http://customshop.yandasmusic.com/custom-bass-guitars/build-your-own-music-man-classic-sting-ray-4